# dispersive relation for linearized Euler-Poisson equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, dispersive-pde

Euler-poisson equation written :
$$n_t+(nu)_x=0$$
$$u_t+uu_x=-\phi_x$$
$$\phi_{xx}=e^\phi-n$$
And linearized following ways:
The system has a constant solution $n=1, \phi=u=0$. By assuming that the system is slightly perturbed, we let
$$n(x, t)=1+\epsilon n_1(x, t)$$
$$\phi(x, t)=\epsilon\phi_1(x, t)$$
$$u(x, t)=\epsilon u_1(x, t)$$
Plugging this into the equations and dropping the terms larger that the first order, we get
$$n_{1t}+u_{1x}=0$$
$$u_{1t}+\phi_{1x}=0$$
$$\phi_{1xx}+n_1-\phi_1=0$$
Now, differentiate the last equation with respect to time twice
$$\phi_{1xxtt}+n_{1tt}-\phi_{1tt}=0$$
From the first equation it then follows
$$\phi_{1xxtt}-u_{1tx}-\phi_{1tt}=0$$
And from the second one
$$\phi_{1xxtt}+\phi_{1xx}-\phi_{1tt}=0$$
$$\therefore (I-\partial_{x}^2)\phi_{1tt}-\phi_{1xx}=0$$

Now question: the dispersive relation of linearized eqution is
$$\omega (k)=k(1+k^2)^{-1/2}$$

How can we get this dispersive relation???

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be $\omega(k) = k(1+k^2)^{-1/2}$?

Comment: A plane wave with wave-number $k$ is on the form $\phi = e^{i(\omega(k)t - kx)}$. Insert this into the PDE and solve for $\omega(k)$.

Comment: Sorry I add " -" sign now.

Comment: Thank you I got it now!